# Alternatives for Windows Phone 8 development

Tags: windows-phone-8

I researched a little, and I found nothing, unless the Windows Phone SDK, that couldn't install on Windows 7 operating system...

There is another way, another SDK, another language, to create Windows Phone 8 applications? For instance, can I use QT for this purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows 8 or 8.1 are required. QT generates a Visual Studio project which needs to be built with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1

If you don't want to upgrade your main system to Windows 8 you can run it in a VM, although there will be issues running the emulator so you may need a physical phone to test (depending on your computer you may need that anyway: modern computers almost all support Hyper-V, but older Windows 7 era computers are more likely not to).

Comment: I understand. Too bad for me, I cannot upgrade my system at the moment. So, I think that I will take a look on cordova.

Comment: Cordova has the same requirements. It depends on the Windows Phone SDK to create the Windows Phone host app. If you cannot upgrade then you can run Windows 8.1 in a VM

Answer (score 0):

You can use `javascript` and `html5` through `cordova phonegap` or [winjs](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/winjs) from Microsoft.